# Как защитить Tinymce от ввода скриптов?

Tags: безопасность, tinymce, textarea

У меня на сайте есть админский блок, в котором пользователи редактируют информацию о себе. И там есть текстовое поле к которому я привязал редактор (TINYMCE), но получается чтобы все тэги работали правильно htmlspecialchars уже не применить.

И соответственно, из этого появилась вероятность, что пользователь может ввести какой нибудь скрипт и запустить его...

Как быть в данном случае?

Comment: почему htmlspecialchars не подходит? Защита какого рода Вам нужна? от SQL инъекций, или xss?

Comment: htmlspecialchars не подходит потому что теги нужно оставить!!!! а запретить только <script>...</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед сохранением в БД удаляйте скрипты регуляркой, например

```
$text = preg_replace('|<script.*</script>|Uis', '', $text);
```

Или, гораздо лучше, используйте [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), например:

```
$allowed_tags = '<br><div><span>'; //Перечислите теги которые можно НЕ удалять
$text = strip_tags($text, $allowed_tags);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!! Я впринципе про регулярку и думал, но сделаю с помощью strip_tags();

Comment: Павел, здравствуйте! 

Я попробовал сделать через регулярку.. И там есть одна проблемка, если скрипт написан не в одну строку, тот вариант регулярной функции, который Вы предложили не подходит, я попробовал сам доработать её, но что то не получилось. Если не сложно подскажите, что нужно в регулярку добавить?

А вообще я сделал так:
$text = preg_replace('|<script>|i', '', $text);
$text = preg_replace('|</script>|i', '', $text);
хотябы убиваю сам тэг <script>, чтобы он не запустился...

Comment: @makan Подредактировал свой ответ, попробуйте сейчас. У меня все работает прекрасно.

Comment: просто замени '<script' на '&#60;script' на отображение это никак не повлияет но вот скрипт работать уже не будет.  
И не забудь '</script'

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую!!

Comment: А потом будете регуляркой вычищать всякие `<object>`, `onmouseover="..."`, `style="foo: expression(...)"`, XML'ные неймспейсы а-ля `<html:script xmlns:html="...">` и еще кучу фокусов.

Только нормальный парсинг и белые списки разрешенных тегов и атрибутов/значений. Не распарсилось, есть сомнения — отфильтровали. Все остальное — ерунда. Особенно костыли на регэкспах.